# HTML5 data- attribute how to retrive value

Tags: lightning, javascript, aura

All, I am dynamically creating a component with this code:

```
$A.createComponent (
              "aura:html",{
              "tag": "input",
              "aura:id":"dayInput" +dayInputCounter,
              "HTMLAttributes": {"class":"dayInput " + dayInput, "id":"dayInput" +dayInputCounter, "type": "number", "step": ".5", "disabled": disabled, "data-date": moment(calcDate).format('l'), "title" : moment(calcDate).format('l')}
```

And I am trying to retrieve it using various methods but none work.

```
weekStart = cmp.find("dayInput"+startCell).get("v.HTMLAttributes").data-date; 
                weekEnd = cmp.find("dayInput"+endCell).get("v.HTMLAttributes").data-date;
```

Answer (score 1):

You use [dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset), as in:

```
someElement.dataset.date;
```

Note that `-` is a math operator, so any letter, aside from the first, prefixed with a `-` will be a capital letter:

```
data-my-element="some value"
```

Becomes:

```
someElement.dataset.myElement;
```

Note that you can't dynamically generate `aura:id` values, so your code won't work anyways. Try:

```
cmp.find("dayInput")[startCell].dataset.date;
```

Comment: First, thanks for the fast reply. I tried the code listed and received: TypeError: Action failed: c:C10_TimeSheetInterface$controller$handleDateChange [can't access property 0, cmp.find(...) is undefined]

Comment: So, the aura:id is dayInput with a number at the end like dayInput0, dayInput1. So I tried it like this> ```weekStart = cmp.find("dayInput"+startCell).dataset.date;
                weekEnd = cmp.find("dayInput"+endCell).dataset.date; ``` This is what I received as an error> TypeError: Action failed: c:C10_TimeSheetInterface$controller$handleDateChange [can't access property "date", cmp.find(...).dataset is undefined]

Comment: FYI I can get the title by doing this:  ```weekStart = cmp.find("dayInput"+startCell).get("v.HTMLAttributes").title; 
                weekEnd = cmp.find("dayInput"+endCell).get("v.HTMLAttributes").title; ```

Comment: @JasonPate Oh, I see what you did. You should probably just use a static id so you can use a list.